# Looking for sequences without duplicates - SQL

Tags: sql, sequence, presto, gaps-and-islands

First time on stack overflow.

I need to find sequences without duplicates using SQL only.

If my data is (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZP6Iw.jpg)

```
System   | date | hour
---------+------+-------
Word     | 28/8 | 16:00
Word     | 28/8 | 16:01
Excel    | 28/8 | 16:02
Word     | 28/8 | 16:03
Ppt      | 28/8 | 16:04
Ppt      | 28/8 | 16:05
```

Then my output will be the systems I used but if I used a system more than once without another system "in the middle", it will be written once. It's not regular "remove duplicates" issue. The duplicates are only when two identical systems are one after the other.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG7Cn.jpg)

```
System  | date  
--------+-------
Word    | 28/8
Excel   | 28/8 
Word    | 28/8 
Ppt     | 28/8
```

I use presto where I'm limited with functions like 'while'.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What variety and version of SQL are you using?

Comment: From the description of the [tag:sql] tag: *Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead.* Yours seems to be missing the code example, table structure, and DBMS-specific tag.

Comment: I use presto (through superset) and it seems to be limited. Thr the table structure is 3 fields as shown: system, date, hour. Sample data is there. Code example: I still don't have, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have any column for Ordering?

Comment: First time I notice a question with the presto tag.  From [this documentation](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/index.html) it looks like presto uses something close to standard SQL.  Interesting, this reminds me of an old IBM software at a previous job that functioned as a SQL proxy to informix databases.

Comment: Answer to mkRabbani: yes, the order is by hour.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have no way to test against a presto I don't know if this will actually work.
So this is just some standard SQL that uses the LAG window function to filter out the same following "System" on the same date.

```
SELECT q.System, q.date
FROM
(
    SELECT 
     t.System, 
     t.date,
     t.hour,
     LAG(t.System) OVER (PARTITION BY t.date ORDER BY t.hour ASC) AS prevSystem
    FROM YourTable t
) AS q
WHERE (q.System != q.prevSystem OR q.prevSystem IS NULL)
ORDER BY q.date, q.hour
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try and let you know! Didn't know this function.

Comment: Well, they didn't really put extensive documentation about the windows functions [here](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/window.html).  So I can only assume it should work. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-island problem. You want to group consecutive records that belong to the same `System`.

You can solve it with window functions (that are available in presto):

```
select min(system) system, min(date) date, count(*) nb_records
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(order by date, hour) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by system order by date, hour) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by rn1 - rn2
order by min(rn1)
```

I would strongly suggest that you merge columns `date` and `time` to a unique column in the relevant date/time datatype. Splitting this information on two columns makes it just more complicated to use it.

In **[this Db Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7a645d3c169fa73ae0089cacadab652e)** with your sample data, the query returns:

```
system | date                | nb_records
:----- | :------------------ | ---------:
Word   | 28/08/2019 00:00:00 |          2
Excel  | 28/08/2019 00:00:00 |          1
Word   | 28/08/2019 00:00:00 |          1
Ppt    | 28/08/2019 00:00:00 |          2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I used "lead" instead and it works!